# how to write limit tends to variable $s_i$?

Tags: symbols

I do not want to write limit tends to infinite, instead of infinite it should be variable:

```
$$\lim_{x\to\variable} f(x) = max(R)$$
```

How may I write in LaTeX code?

Comment: Just replace \variable with a space followed by the variable.  Also, use \[ and \] instead of $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the usual `\infty` with your variable. Also better not use `$$` and it should read `\max`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \max(R)
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
  \lim_{x\to s_i}f(x)
```

in math mode.